# What qualifies as a (slow) access to an internal element of a LinkedList

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

A post on LinkedList says:

LinkedList allows for constant-time insertions or removals, but only sequential access of elements. In other words, `you can walk the list forwards or backwards, but grabbing an element in the middle` takes time proportional to the size of the list.

I'm not understanding what will qualify for grabbing the element in the middle?

In below piece of code, assuming `arrL` is a LinkedList that holds 50 elemnets, when counter `j` reaches 20, and program executes `arrL.get(20)`.. Does that mean program is grabbing the element in middle? Also in below program I'm just walking the list forward, isn't?

```
    for(int j=0;j<arrL.size();++j){
        arrL.get(j);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in each iteration you are traversing the list from the beginning to the *j-th* element, so the overall loop performance is `n^2` (very poor). That's because in each iteration you have independent `get()` call which has linear performance.

If you use iterator on the other hand, you will be traversing the list one element at a time, going forward by one element in each iteration, which is much faster:

```
for(Iterator<E> iter = arrL.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
  E e = iter.next();
}
```

or better:

```
for(E k: arrL) {
}
```

*BTW this is a **very** basic data-structure question, Java has nothing to do here...*

Answer (score 1):

For LinkedList, get(N) takes time proportional to N. So - get(19) takes about 20 times as long as get(0). Your for loop above operates in O(n^2) time - n passes, with O(n) time for each pass. If you want to access the members in order, use an iterator:

```
Iterator it = arrL.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
   it.next();
}
```

or implicity, like so:

```
for(Obj o : arrL) {
  // do something with o
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a linked list, each list entry only knows its predecessor and its successor: They simply link to one another. The good thing about this is, that it is easy to make this list to grow by just adding and linking to new elements. But reaching an element that is not an endpoint in the list requires a walk from either end to the specific element. Therefore, each call to `get(j)` requires `j` element visits from an endpoint in the chain/list. `get(j)` is, in other words, quite expensive in terms of time. As an example, if the list has 1000 elements, getting to element number 500 requires 500 visits from either end. If the list were 2000 elements long, getting to the middle element (element 1000) would similarly require 1000 visits because we follow the node links (the chain).

In contrast, accessing any element in an array takes constant time.

Answer (score 0):

@Vicky, what it means is that every time you call `arraL.get(j)` this operation takes linear time to perform. That means that when you're getting the 20th element, it will start at the beginning (or end, I'm not sure about the implementation) and transverse the entire list to the 20th element.
The other implementation `ArrayList` will do that in constant time (internally it keeps an array, so you can think about `arrL.get(20)`as `array[20]`), but every time you delete an item in the middle, it will have to shift the elements in the array.
So basically, `ArrayList` is a better choice, performance wise,for random reads, and `LinkedList` is a better choice when you will be performing a lot of deletes.